# Java method which returns first date available

Tags: java, date, search

i'm having a problem with a project i'm going to submit soon (it's for an exam).

It's a program made of several methods, but i need some help at this point:

I need to generate today's date -i am forced to use Date and Calendar, even if Date is deprecated, it's a mandatory for this exam- and then check if in my vector already exists a booking or not for that date.

If a booking already exists for today, the method has to tell me the first available date.

i.e: today is 12/04/2019, I don't have any bookings for today, the program tells me 12/04/2019 is the first available date.

If not, it will check if for tomorrow there are bookings. If 13/04/2019 is not in my vector, it will return me that 13/04/2019 is the first available date.

The program includes adding and deleting bookings.

With this code everything works (I've also tryed adding a  do-while and a nested for loop, but nothing changes), but not always: on the first compile, i.e., i have a blank field for dateAvailable.

Can you help me?

```
    private void firstAVdate() {

        Date data = new Date();

        String dataStr;
        boolean tuttoOK;


        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat ("dd/MM/yyyy");

        dataStr=formatter.format(data); 
        String dateAvailable=dataStr; 

        System.out.println("Current date : ");
        System.out.println(dataStr);


        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();


        if (vect.size()>0) {

            for (int i=0; i<vect.size(); i++) {


                if (vect.get(i).getDataString().equals(dataStr)) { 

                    c.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);

                    dataStr = formatter.format(c.getTime());

                    dateAvailable=dataStr;
                }
            }

            System.out.println("");
            System.out.println("First available date:");
            System.out.println(dateAvailable);  

        }else {
            System.out.println("No bookings available.");
        }

    }
```

Comment: Which data structure is this `vect`.

Comment: To test the equality of 2 date objects use `date1.compareTo(date2) == 0` where `date1` and `date2` are date objects.

Comment: `vect` is a  vector:  `private Vector <BookingSystem> vect= new Vector <BookingSystem>();`

Comment: Please post `BookingSystem` code also.

Comment: I would if I could, it's for an exam and I think my professor is among us. Can I send it in a pm in any way? Btw i don't have any problems with the other parts of my program. The operations involving the vector work great. This method serves a separate function of the whole thing (is called inside a switch case, with a input letter)

Comment: "I would if I could, it's for an exam and I think my professor is among us." I love this. Thank you for posting that :) You should provide the results you are getting. You have told us what you expect, but not what you are actually getting.

Comment: @SamratV works the same as .equals

Comment: @ck1221 not sure but i have to send my project soon and i don't want to be risky in any way

Comment: @ck1221 i get: `Current date : 
12/04/2019

First available date:
13/04/2019` because i have already saved a booking for today. but then, if i restart the program, it says `Current date : 
12/04/2019

First available date:
        `

Comment: @C____ you are making mistake while comparing the dates most probably.

Comment: @ck1221 i've already done that. Also tryed putting some prints inside my code. But I literally don't get why dateStr is empty only when i start the program for the first time. i've also tryed nesting another for inside (and the outer one stopping at position -1 in that case), which checks position i+1 and then compairs each date inside my vector with another date incremented by one day, but nothing changes

Comment: also tryed putting the prints at the bottom inside my for loop but that seems wrong. but nothing btw @ck1221

Comment: The best way to get help for this is to post code that will compile and run. With out that we can't debug the code properly. Have you tried setting a break point and debugging? If not I highly recommend you learn how to do that and use that tool to your advantage.

Comment: Already done. It seems my problems depend on savings, the code works

Comment: What a mess. Teachers that force students to use `Date` and `Calendar` in 2019 deserve to be shot. All my sympathy. They should encourage your use of [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you meant that your vector includes all the booked dates.
(Your code says the opposite).

So I would have used a Hash Table structure for booked dates.

Think of it as a pool of dates; if you want to book a date you first check if he is present in the Hash Table, if not you just "throw" it in.

So this is an abstraction code (only written logically, not to be copied!):

```
initially:
HashTable ht = new HashTable;

book_a_date(String date):
if(!ht.contains(date)) { 
    ht.add(date);
    return date + " successfully booked!";
}
else {
    date = next day;
    return book_a_date(date);
}

unbook_a_date(String date):
if(ht.contains(date) {
    ht.remove(date);
}
```

Comment: my vector is dynamically filled with bookings and its content can be saved in a file (dat or txt). The first if in the code is only to check if the vector is empty. I would have used hash tables but, sadly, i'm not allowed.

Comment: OK. I checked your code again and it still isn't clear to me what you're trying to do, but I suggest that you add a break statement at the end of the inner if statement. Why do you print "No bookings available" if the vector is empty? Isn't it the opposite?

Comment: because if my vector is empty (no data inside), i have to print " no bookings available". Just ignore that.

Answer (score 0):

You need a double loop. For every date you want to check, you need to check it against every entry in your vector until one matches.

It will probably be easier to manage if you write an auxiliary method `isDateBooked` that determines whether your vector already contains a booking for a given date. This method would contain a loop that iterates over the elements of the vector until a date matches. You then call `isDateBooked` from within a loop that iterates over the dates until `isDateBooked` returns false.

### java.time

And I know that you are not allowed, but for everyone else reading along: Don’t use `SimpleDateFormat`, `Date` and `Calendar`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated. Use `LocalDate` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). Also `BookingSystem.getDataString()` should not return a string but a `LocalDate` (and should of course be named accordingly). Using java.time in this way would have made your job a lot easier and given clearer code.